# What's the scripting language that works best when binding with c++?

Tags: c++, binding, scripting-language

I am working on a project that heavily relies on many c++ objects that I created. In stead of compiling the codes every time when I use different objects, I am thinking using scripts that can instantiate c++ objects and call their functions without recompiling. What are the possible candidates? Thanks for the answer in advance.

Comment: it's offtopic, but lua is a popular option

Comment: This does not sound like a good idea, but if you are on Windows, use COM.

Comment: I am using linux, but from what I heard as well, lua works pretty well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sol2](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2) is a good C++ wrapper for Lua: it offers fast execution time and minimal dependencies.

An alterantive is [ChaiScript](http://chaiscript.com), but it's not as fast as sol2.